# Manage Login Redirection in Pyrocms

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I need to manage login in such a way that it should redirect the control after successful login to the page which call login method in pyrocms.

By default it return control to Home Page. for example i want to go gallery page but it require user to be logged in so it will redirect control to the login page and now i want to redirect the control back to the gallery page once the user successful logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, i have come with the exact solution which is working correctly for me.

Whenever user try to view the gallery page(restricted page) which require user login, we have to only assign the URL where we want to redirect after successful login in $redirect_to in the controller method:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('redirect_to',$redirect_to);
```

Then it will automatically redirect the control to the desired page. Because in the users controller the login function is developed in such a way that:

```
$redirect_to = $this->input->post('redirect_to') ? $this->input->post('redirect_to') : $this->session->userdata('redirect_to');
```

Hopefully this will help you sometime

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer... you can accept your own answer if you want to, incidentally