# pyrocms social module: how to register new user with facebook connect

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm still new to CI and PyroCMS, and am trying to implement a Facebook login using the [Social module](https://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/social_integration) in a custom module, which looks like it does everything I want, but I'm clearly missing some basics (I can't find any documentation other than the [brief readme](https://github.com/pyrocms/social))!

So far, I've watched the [intro video](http://player.vimeo.com/video/33459969), and have enabled Facebook successfully. I can connect via FB and see FB listed in /social/linked, but some confusion exists in my mind between the two user groups I've got: admin and user.

The flow I'm trying to construct is:

- user arrives at the site and is presented with a survey
- user fills in the survey, then is asked to signup (I understand that this is unconventional)
- /signup has a facebook connect button, supplied by the social module
- user clicks the connect button, and grants permission in facebook's popup window
- user should be directed back to /signup, (or maybe redirected to /user/registration) with some details filled in from facebook (eg. email, name)
- on submit, user should be added to the users table, as a member of the 'users' group (not admin) with no email activation required
- an email is sent, thanks page is displayed
- on returning to the site, the user should access their on-site profile using facebook connect.

I've read a bunch of threads on the subject, which have shaped these expectations...

Here's where I'm at:

- user arrives, fills in survey, clicks the connect button
- user is redirected to the homepage, which displays a standard page (not handled by my module).  I need to return to /signup!

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328141/manage-login-redirection-in-pyrocms/10382779#10382779), I've tried setting:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('redirect_to', '/signup');
```

in what I believe is the correct controller method (checks to see if the user is logged in before sending the email, then calls template build to display the social buttons), to no avail.

(edit: I now see that the code above relates to the user module, not the social module.. maybe i can transplant some changes...)

**My questions:**

- am i on the right track, or going about this the wrong way?!
- am i right in thinking that the FB account will be matched with an existing user if the email addresss exists in the system?
- I have only one FB account, which I is authorised for the app, and I'm using to connect with as a user - will this work, or do I need a separate FB account to test as user?

Other notes:

- I am testing the site in Chrome, logged in as admin in Firefox.
- Facebook is my testcase, I'm looking at supporting FB, LinkedIn, google and Twitter eventually.

Phew! Grateful for any feedback, Tim

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer some of your questions since i'm currently experimenting with the exact same social module as well and with some addons to it.

> am i right in thinking that the FB account will be matched with an
>   existing user if the email addresss exists in the system?

Yes you are. I checked it myself while troubleshooting the fact that my google (gmail address) could'nt connect while my hotmail (registered email) could. You will have to sync your emails in all your social sites, change the loginsystem (allowing username login for example) or manually connect multiple emails in your account settings..

> I have only one FB account, which I is authorised for the app, and I'm using to connect with as a user - will this work, or do I need a separate FB account to test as user?

I suggest u let someone with another FB account test the system (better save then sorry) but in my case I didn't have any troubles using other (normal) accounts to log in.

> am i on the right track, or going about this the wrong way?!

This was your first question, but I'll answer this as the last on since I didn't test is myself:

The Facebook App has a setting called "Site URL". This is the url to which will be redirected. Simply change it to the page you wish it to be. You can also try to change the following lines in social/controllers/social.php:

Line 245 (redirect: user is logged in after FB connect)

```
redirect($this->input->get('success_url') ? $this->input->get('success_url') : 'social/linked');
```

Line 283 (redirect: user has to fill in some additional fields to complete registration)

```
redirect('users/register');
```

Good luck!

Comment: cheers for the detailed answer - I'll be back on this project in a week; no doubt, I'll be accepting your answer as soon as I try it out! many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The intro video shows off the entire extent of the social module. Frontend registrations, frontend user account linking, and backend account linking for the entire system.

If you wish to integrate custom functionality, custom user flows and other stuff as listed in your question then you will need to do a little custom work with the module. Hack it, extend it, send in some pull requests, whatever, but sadly it cannot do "everything to integrate with everywhere ever" out of the box. :-/

Comment: I'm stoked that you've given us social,  and I certainly don't expect it to make me toast - just wrapping my head around the game! tx!

Comment: I'd need to make some sort of "User Flow" feature, which would be pretty tricky but probably just about work. You define where they are coming from and where they should go after registration, with what extra information to be asked for and mark out which networks are supported. That however, would be a massive job and is out of the scope of the original "help them register with as much info as networks will provide to pre-populate the form" design.